# SQL JDBC: parent key not found BUT the parent values have already been inserted into the database

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, jdbc, terminal

I'm having a problem inserting mock data into the database 
The table I'm trying to insert the values into is called 'purchased'
which has some foreign key values such as patient_id, pharmacy_id, drug_id.

The other 3 tables 'patient', 'pharmacy', 'drug' have already been added to the database successfully.

Patient table has a foreign key which is doctor_id. The 'doctor' table has also been added to the database.

Since I know that a foreign key patient_id in 'purchased' table depends upon another foreign key doctod_id, so I've done something like this

foreign key (patient_id, receipt_no) references **patient(patient_id,doctor_id)** ON DELETE CASCADE

Not sure what I've missed here, why does sqlplus complain that the parent key is not found? Just working for a database class project so I'm still learning.

Here's .sql code file 
https://gist.github.com/mopkaloppt/de8fbf64c4d5711c90e2b389a72911ba

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.. I'm freaking out a bit now as I've been struggling with this for a while and it's due soon :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your FK constraint looks confused:

```
foreign key (patient_id, receipt_no) references patient(patient_id,doctor_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                         ^^^^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

You are getting the errors because there is no `receipt_no` in your `purchased` data that matches a `doctor_id`.  This is perhaps unsurprising as the data are unrelated.

Having looked at the data in your `patient` table, it seems you haven't got the database design quite right.  There's duplication in that table: if a patient has multiple illnesses or sees multiple doctors then there are repeated values for all other columns.  This is also getting in the way of your FK constraint: you are trying to link a row in `purchased` to a patient, but there are multiple rows for some patients, so which row do you link to?

It seems you have a many-to-many relationship between patients and illnesses (a patient can have multiple illnesses, multiple patients can have an illness), and also between patients and doctors (a patient can be seen by multiple doctors, a doctor can see multiple patients).  So, I would recommend introducing new tables for the relationships between patients and illnesses, and between patients and doctors.  For example, here's the table you could use for the relationship between patients and doctors.  Insert one row into this table for each combination of patient and doctor:

```
create table patient_doctor (
  patient_id char(4) not null,
  doctor_id char (4) not null,
  primary key (patient_id, doctor_id),
  foreign key (patient_id) references patient(patient_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (doctor_id) references doctor(doctor_id) on delete cascade);
```

A linking table such as this is the standard way of representing a many-to-many connection in a relational database.

You don't yet have a table for illnesses, so I'll leave you to create a table for them, a linking table similar to that for patients and doctors (`patient_illness` perhaps), and the data in both tables.

Once you've done that, remove the `doctor_id` and `illness` columns from `patient`, remove the duplicate rows and make the `patient` PK depend only on `patient`.  Your FK constraint from `purchased` to `patient` can then reference only `patient_id`.

Hopefully after doing all of this you should see your FK constraint violation errors go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer Luke!
It works now :)